# mysql error 1175 while using inner query

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have 2 tables - `item_images` and `images`.

When I run query

```
SELECT image_id FROM item_images WHERE item_id=1
```

I get `image_id` values `5`, `6`

When I run

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE id in (5, 6);
```

It also works and deletes these 2 rows.

But when I try to chain these 2 queries together, it fails with error 1175.

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE id in (SELECT image_id FROM item_images WHERE item_id=1);

    Error Code: 
1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.000 sec
```

id field is set as private key, not null.

Why does this happen if if id in WHERE is clearly private key?

Is the only way to go around this is to disable safe mode, or is there another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `id` column (`images` table) is always greater than zero: `... WHERE id > 0 AND id in (SELECT image_id ...`.

Comment: @wchiquito, interesting - but I'm getting `Syntax error: unexpected 'in' (in)` when I try this :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id` column (`images` table) is always greater than zero (0):

```sql
mysql> SET SESSION SQL_SAFE_UPDATES := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item_images`, `images`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_images` (
    ->   `item_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `image_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `images`
    -> VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL),
    ->        (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `item_images`
    ->   (`item_id`, `image_id`)
    -> VALUES (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1),
    ->        (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 2);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `image_id`
    -> FROM `item_images`
    -> WHERE `item_id` = 1;
+----------+
| image_id |
+----------+
|        5 |
|        6 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE
    -> FROM `images`
    -> WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `image_id`
    ->                FROM `item_images`
    ->                WHERE `item_id` = 1);
ERROR 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update
                    a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column

mysql> DELETE
    -> FROM `images`
    -> WHERE `id` > 0 AND
    ->       `id` IN (SELECT `image_id`
    ->                FROM `item_images`
    ->                WHERE `item_id` = 1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mEAXYEPooNWKyrK28X1xar/0).

**UPDATE**

In the first `DELETE` the index (`key`) is not reached.

```sql
mysql> SET SESSION SQL_SAFE_UPDATES := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN DELETE
    -> FROM `images`
    -> WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `image_id`
    ->                FROM `item_images`
    ->                WHERE `item_id` = 1);
+----+--------------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE             | images      | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | item_images | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 |    16.67 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN DELETE
    -> FROM `images`
    -> WHERE `id` > 0 AND
    ->       `id` IN (SELECT `image_id`
    ->                FROM `item_images`
    ->                WHERE `item_id` = 1);
+----+--------------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE             | images      | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const |    6 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | item_images | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |    6 |    16.67 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mEAXYEPooNWKyrK28X1xar/2).

Comment: Any idea why mysql acts this way and works only when you insert id > 0?

Comment: @Ward: Updated answer.

Comment: Detailed and helpful. Thanks!